# Clearing global history in PuTTY

Tags: bash, ssh, putty

I was wonder how Putty stores history. I have server and multiple account there. Every account has a history when I use "history" it lists the history from that account. Is there something like global history of all accounts? If it exists how can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuTTY does not keep any history.

It's a remote shell that does.

It's obviously shell-specific, where the history is kept in.

For example for `bash`, it's `.bash_history` file in the account's home folder.